# How to plot quaternion constraint equation vs time

Tags: euler

If K = q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2 + q4^2 and K0 = q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2 + q4^2 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1, how to plot K-K0 vs time graph. K is the quaternion constraint equations where the quaternions are changing with time. K0 is K at initial time. What equations do I need to find quaternions as a function of time? I have angular velocity and the dynamic differential equations (angular velocity dot). Can I find K as a function of time with that information?

Answer (score 1):

> What equations do I need to find quaternions as a function of time? I have angular velocity

This reference [page 14](https://faculty.sites.iastate.edu/jia/files/inline-files/quaternion.pdf?#page=14) and [page 16](https://faculty.sites.iastate.edu/jia/files/inline-files/quaternion.pdf?#page=16) give the equation describing the derivative of the quaternion in terms of angular velocity $\omega$. This equation can be integrated to get the quaternion at any given time instant.

The equations are
$$
\dot{q}_{(t)} = \frac{1}{2}\ \omega_{(t)}\otimes q_{(t)}\quad \text{or}\\
\dot{q}_{(t)} = \frac{1}{2}\ \ q_{(t)} \otimes \omega_{\mathcal{B}(t)}
$$
Be careful

> Can I find K as a function of time with that information?

Yes. Solve for $q_{(t)}$ first. Then compute K from the result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924782